# Is multiple imputation worth doing at all for data missing completely at random?

Tags: missing-data, multiple-imputation, efficiency

If data are missing completely at random (MCAR), then obviously multiple imputation (MI) won't serve its lauded function of lessening bias in your findings, since there's no bias to lessen. However, perhaps it will increase efficiency, and make an uncertain finding more certain. I know that if you do it right, then MI won't manufacture undue certainty and will preserve all the certainty that is appropriate given the fact that you are not in fact observing what you have imputed, but if you have a lot of values that you can validly impute with high confidence, then will that increase your overall efficiency and improve your chances of getting significant findings when in fact there are significant findings to be had? Or will MI on any MCAR data just result in the same findings with the same confidence intervals that you would get if you just used the observations after listwise deletion?

Comment: You still need a method to do the imputation and multiple imputation is as good as any.  It does give unbiased estimates.  The results depend on the problem and the inference you want to make.

Comment: But my question is if imputation will change any results at all, compared to doing listwise deletion, if the missingness is completely at random.

Comment: I would say that if you were able to recover the missing value perfectly then you would have a bigger sample, and then, more statistical power.

Comment: That's my intuition as well - I can imagine a situation where the multiple correlations between the variables are so strong that the several imputed datasets all have almost exactly the same imputed values, in which case the separate models would all have very small CIs (assuming of course that the correlation you're looking for really exists) and then the averaged model would have a small CI. But I'm hoping that someone can maybe give me a proof or refer me to a proof, or just anything where MI was used or discussed in the presence of MCAR.